# How to minimize run time with large data set (Make list of unique objects from list of 93,773 objects)

Tags: c#, algorithm, json.net, runtime

We are extracting a large amount of JSON objects from an EVE Online API, and deseralizing them into EveObjModel objects using Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert. From there we want to create a list of unique objects, i.e. the most expensive of each type_id. I have pasted the dataContract below as well.

**The problem:** This code below can handle smaller sets of data, but it is not viable with larger amounts. Currently, we are running it through and it takes more than 50 minutes (and counting). What can we do to reduce the time it takes to run through larger sets of data to a bearable level?

Thank you for your time. Fingers crossed.

```
    // The buyList contains about 93,000 objects. 
    public void CreateUniqueBuyList(List<EveObjModel> buyList)
    {

        List<EveObjModel> uniqueBuyList = new List<EveObjModel>();

        foreach (EveObjModel obj in buyList)
        {
            int duplicateCount = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < uniqueBuyList.Count; i++)
            {
                if (uniqueBuyList[i].type_id == obj.type_id)
                       duplicateCount++;
            }

            if (duplicateCount == 1)
            {
                foreach (EveObjModel objinUnique in uniqueBuyList)
                {
                    if (obj.type_id == objinUnique.type_id && obj.price > objinUnique.price)
                    {
                        // instead of adding obj, the price is just changed to the price in the obj. 
                        objinUnique.price = obj.price;

                    }
                    else if (obj.type_id == objinUnique.type_id && obj.price == objinUnique.price)
                    {
                        //uniqueBuyList.RemoveAll(item => item.type_id == obj.type_id);

                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        // Hitting this  mean that there are other objects with same type and higher price OR its not the same type_id
                    }

                }
            }
            else if (duplicateCount > 1)
            {
                // shud not happn...
            }
            else
            {

                uniqueBuyList.Add(obj);
            }


            continue;
        }
        foreach (EveObjModel item in uniqueBuyList.OrderBy(item => item.type_id))
        {
            buyListtextField.Text += $"Eve Online Item! Type-ID is: {item.type_id}, Price is {item.price}\n";
        }
    }
```

This is our EveObjModel class

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Runtime.Serialization;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace EveOnlineApp
    {
    [DataContract]
         public class EveObjModel
    {
    [DataMember]
    public bool is_buy_order { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public double price { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int type_id { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Comment: What is the part that's taking long and how large are the objects? Downloading almost 94 thousand objects might take a while (depending on how large they are)

Comment: @MindSwipe Downloading the objects take about 2,5 minutes. We will have to look into this is as well, but the issue above still amounts to over 99% of the run time. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not surprising that the process is slow, because the algorithm you are using (with nested loop) has at least quadratic O(N*N) time complexity, which with such size of data sets is really slow.

One way is to use LINQ `GroupBy` operator, which internally uses hash based lookup, hence has theoretically O(N) time complexity. So you group by `type_id` and for each group (list of elements with the same key) take the one with the maximum `price`:

```
var uniqueBuyList = buyList
    .GroupBy(e => e.type_id)
    .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(e => e.price).First())
    .ToList();
```

Of cource you don't need to sort the list in order to take the element with the max `price`. A better version is to use `Aggregate` method (which is basically `foreach` loop) for that:

```
var uniqueBuyList = buyList
    .GroupBy(e => e.type_id)
    .Select(g => g.Aggregate((e1, e2) => e1.price > e2.price ? e1 : e2))
    .ToList();
```

Another non LINQ based way is to sort the input list by `type_id` ascending, `price` descending. Then do a single loop over the sorted list and take the first element of each `type_id` group (it will have the maximum `price`):

```
var comparer = Comparer<EveObjModel>.Create((e1, e2) =>
{
    int result = e1.type_id.CompareTo(e2.type_id);
    if (result == 0) // e1.type_id == e2.type_id
        result = e2.price.CompareTo(e1.price); // e1, e2 exchanged to get descending order
    return result;
});
buyList.Sort(comparer);
var uniqueBuyList = new List<EveObjModel>();
EveObjModel last = null;
foreach (var item in buyList)
{
    if (last == null || last.type_id != item.type_id)
        uniqueBuyList.Add(item);
    last = item;
}
```

The complexity of this algorithm is O(N*log(N)), so it's worse than the hash based algorithms (but much better than original). The benefit is that it uses less memory and the resulting list is already sorted by `type_id`, so you don't need to use `OrderBy`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. It is very helpful!

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use `Enumerable.GroupBy()` to do this fairly efficiently:

```
var grouped = buyList.GroupBy(item => item.type_id);

var uniqueBuyList = new List<EveObjModel>();

foreach (var group in grouped)
{
    var combined = group.First();
    combined.price = group.Max(item => item.price);
    uniqueBuyList.Add(combined);
}
```

Or alternatively (but more difficult to read):

```
var uniqueBuyList = buyList.GroupBy(item => item.type_id).Select(group =>
{
    var combined = group.First();
    combined.price = group.Max(item => item.price);
    return combined;
}).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. We will try out both the solutions and time it.

Answer (score 1):

We can sort given List by ascending `type_id` and then by ascending `price` and reverse it. So that, `EveObjModel` object with `higher price` come first for every unique `type_id`.

Then, we may go through object List again and pick up the unique type_id that come fist and skip same type_id then after.

As we are only sorting once, this will cause us time complexity of `O(n * log n)`. Since, `n = 93773` , logarithm of 93773 in base 2 is nearly = `17`. So, sorting will take overall `n * log n  = 93773 * 17 = 1594141` operations, which can be done in very less amount of time.

Hope following code will help you !

```
public void CreateUniqueBuyList(List<EveObjModel> buyList)
{
    //sort by ascending type_id and then by ascending price and reverse it. so that,
    // object with higher price come first
    List<EveObjModel>tempList = buyList.OrderBy(x => x.type_id).ThenBy(x => x.price).Reverse().ToList();
    List<EveObjModel> uniqueBuyList = new List<EveObjModel>();
    for (int i = 0; i < tempList.Count; ++i) {
        if ((i > 1) && tempList[i - 1].type_id == tempList[i].type_id) continue; // if duplicate type_id then don't take it again
        uniqueBuyList.Add(tempList[i]);
    }

    foreach (EveObjModel item in uniqueBuyList.OrderBy(item => item.type_id))
    {
        buyListtextField.Text += $"Eve Online Item! Type-ID is: {item.type_id}, Price is {item.price}\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. We will try out your solution.